# Delay loop by 1 second

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, delay, settimeout

I need to delay a loop every second, I need to count how many times the loop has iterated, once it hits a divisable of 3 compared to the length, pause for a second, then continue on the loop.

```js
var callsPerSecond = 500;
var len = 1900;
var delay = 1500;
var timeout;

var i = 1; //  set your counter to 1

function myLoop() { //  create a loop function
  setTimeout(function() { //  call a 3s setTimeout when the loop is called
    $('#log').append('<li>called</li>'); //  your code here
    i++; //  increment the counter
    if (i < ((len - (i % callsPerSecond)) / callsPerSecond)) { //  if the counter < 10, call the loop function
      myLoop(); //  ..  again which will trigger another 
    } //  ..  setTimeout()
    console.log(i);
  }, 500)
}

myLoop();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="log"></ul>
```

So I should get 1900 foos in my log, with a delay of a second, 3 times because 1900 is divisable by 500 3 times.

Where am I going wrong? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does what you want:

```js
var callsPerSecond = 500;
var len = 1900;
var delay = 1000;

function myLoop(i) {
  while (i < len) {
    i++;
    console.log('foo' + i);
    if (i % callsPerSecond == 0) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        myLoop(i);
      }, delay);
      break;
    }
  }
};

myLoop(0);
```

When i is divisible by callsPersecond, it calls the myLoop function again after 1000ms and continues counting.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, it is your solution:

```js
var callsPerSecond = 500;
var len = 1900;
var delay = 1000;
var i = 1; //  set your counter to 1

function myLoop() { //  create a loop function
  setTimeout(function() { //  call a 3s setTimeout when the loop is called

    if (i < ((len - (i % callsPerSecond)) / callsPerSecond)) { //  if the counter < 10, call the loop function
      $('#log').append('<li>called</li>'); //  your code here

    } //  ..  setTimeout()

    myLoop(); //  ..  again which will trigger another 
    console.log('foo' + i);
    i++; //  increment the counter
  }, delay)
}

myLoop();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="log"></ul>
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response, it does work, however Ruudts answer is a little nicer on the eyes :)